# Why doesn't line-height work on img elements?

Tags: html, css

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) says `line-height` work on inline elements. Images are inline elements. Then why doesn't `line-height` work on img elements? [Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0km3dun6/) in which line-height doesn't center the image.

Comment: First: line-heigth is not for centering purposes. Second: the line-height doesn't works as you expect, inline elements have a different behaviour with the line size. Try with a <span> with line-height, padding and border, next to another span without line-height, padding but with border.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page you link to says:

> On replaced inline elements such as buttons or other input elements, line-height has no effect.

`img` elements are **replaced** inline elements, so `line-height` has no effect on them.

You need an extra element if you want to set the line height of a line box around an image.

```css
span {
  line-height: 200px;
}
div {
  outline: solid black 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello <span> <img src="http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/iana-logo-header.svg" alt=""> </span> World
</div>

<div>
  Hello
  <img src="http://www.iana.org/_img/2013.1/iana-logo-header.svg" alt="">World
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `line-height` on `div`

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2229/social_media_mini/48/google.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: If I had a `span` instead of an image then I wouldn't need to use `line-height` on `div` -- https://jsfiddle.net/0km3dun6/1/  why?

Comment: I think because `span` element can contain text or other elements but `img` element can't.